# Rails form with url based on input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I feel like there's no easy way to do this in rails, but since I'm fairly noob in rails I decided to ask for solutions:

I have a form in a view that contains a single (text) input. How can I specify the form url such that it will do a `GET` to `/something/<input>` ?

I know I could:

1. use custom javascript code
2. post to an endpoint that would do the redirect

Is there any cleaner way?

(using rails 5.2.1 if relevant)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
<%= form_tag(route_path method: :get) do %>
  search <%= text_field_tag :search %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

It depends on which form helpers you use.

Comment: form_tag is deprecated as stated on https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

In your form:

```
<%= form_with(url: "path_name/input_field_name", method: :get, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :input_field_name %>
  <%= f.submit 'Search', input_field_name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
unless params[:input_field_name].blank?
  @results = ModelName.where('input_field_name iLIKE ?', "%#{params[:input_field_name]}%")
end
```

Comment: This becomes messy when you have nested resources, is there a better way?